# Question and answer mismatch in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, specific-question

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399450/how-do-i-fix-this). Something seriously wrong with this. The question is about Stack Overflow and the answer is related to programming.

Answer (score 19):

The question was edited from the original content to:

> I wanted my question to be deleted but it already had an answer. Ignore and flag because there is no point to this. I already did.

In an attempt to have the question deleted.

I reverted the edit.

Comment: Well, now it makes sense...

Comment: ... and it got deleted anyway. Was that a race condition?